# Play Pokémon Go On An Amazon Fire Phone?

Tags: pokemon-go

Can I play Pokémon Go on an Amazon fire phone? If so, how?

Comment: It doesn't run either Android, nor iOS.  What makes you think it would work?

Comment: You have to flash it with CyanogenMod since only iOS and Android ar supported OSs for Pokemon Go.

Comment: Wait, strike that.  The OS is based on Android.  But the highest it goes is 3.6.5, which doesn't meet the requirements for the game.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a tutorial on how to install Pokemon Go on a Fire OS 5 device:

[pokemongokindlefire.com](http://pokemongokindlefire.com/)

**Breakdown of the procedure:**

Tested OS: Fire OS 5 (Bellini)

1. Go to Settings > Security > and turn on Apps from Unknown Sources (the option may be found under Settings > Applications on older devices)
2. Download the latest [Google Account Manager .APK](http://rawapk.com/google-account-manager-apk-download/)
3. Open the Google Account Manager .APK file and hit Install
4. Download the latest [Google Play Services .APK](http://rawapk.com/google-play-services-apk-download/)
5. Open the Google Play Services .APK file and hit Install
6. Download the latest [Google Services Framework .APK](http://rawapk.com/google-services-framework-apk-download/)
7. Open the Google Services Framework .APK file and hit Install
8. Download the latest [Google Play Store .APK](http://rawapk.com/google-play-store-apk-download/)
9. Open the Google Play Store .APK file and hit Install
10. Restart your tablet
11. Open Google Play
12. Download and install Google Maps
13. Download and install Pokemon GO
14. Go to Settings > Wireless > Location-Based Services > and turn off Location-Based Services – also make sure it is enabled for Maps and Pokemon GO
15. Launch Google Maps and press on the current location icon. It should prompt a Use location? pop-up (this may also pop-up automatically when you launch Google Maps). Press Yes. You should now see your location in Google Maps. Exit Maps and now run Pokemon GO!

---

However, Amazon Fire Phone stopped updating the Fire OS at 4.6 "Sangria" (final minor version was 4.6.6.1), which is a fork of Android 4.4 "KitKat". Fire OS 5 "Bellini" is a fork of Android 5 "Lollipop".

**DISCLAIMER: THIS IS AN UNTESTED PROCEDURE, AND MAY NOT RESULT IN THE ABILITY TO PLAY POKEMON GO ON FIRE PHONE! THAT SAID, [ANDROID 4.4 IS SUPPORTED BY POKEMON GO PER NIANTIC SUPPORT](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices)**

For the procedure on how to install all the required Google .apk files to have access to Google Play Store under Fire OS 4.6 for Fire Phone, visit:

http://spinyourfire.com/fire-phone-tips-and-tricks/amazon-fire-phone-google-play/

The process is roughly the same as above, but the .apk files are most likely different, as they are the ones compatible with Android 4.4 "KitKat":

1. Allow installation of apps not from the Amazon Appstore. To do this, go to Settings > Applications > Allow installation of applications not from the Amazon Appstore  and make sure it’s set to ON.
2. [Download and copy the folder containing these four files](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=1D4FC234619128B5&id=1D4FC234619128B5%213100&authkey=%21APeud0CewmOqxxU) (with Google framework) to your Fire Phone. I suggest simply connecting your Fire phone to your PC and transferring these files to a new folder (I suggest naming it “Google” or something like that). If you don’t know how to do it, read this tutorial: [How To Transfer Files To Fire Phone](http://spinyourfire.com/fire-phone-tips-and-tricks/transfer-files-to-fire-phone/) or [How To Sideload Apps To Fire Phone](http://spinyourfire.com/fire-phone-tips-and-tricks/how-to-sideload-apps-to-fire-phone/).
3. Install ES File Explorer. This app will let you easily manage files on your Fire phone and install apps (in the form of APK files) you transferred. ES File Explorer is available on the Amazon Appstore so all you need to do is click on its link and download the app to your Fire.
4. Now you have to navigate to the folder with Google files you copied to your Fire phone. Obviously, you have to use ES File Explorer to do that.
5. Once you are in the folder, install these files in the following order (not in any other order). Just tap on the file, accept permissions and let them install. Don’t open them until you install all of them.

   - Google Account Manager
   - Google Play Services
   - Google Services Framework
   - Google Play Store
6. Congratulations! You now have Google Play and Google Services installed and (hopefully) working on your Fire phone. Open Play Store and configure you Google account so that you can download and use Google apps (such as Google Calendar, Gmail, Google Chrome, Snapchat and so on) and Google Play as if it was any  other Android device.
7. You might need to update the Play store, so look out for updates to any of the files you just manually installed. To check of the Google Play store is up to date, open it, go to Settings  and click on Build version.
8. You now have to app stores installed with some apps overlapping. In order to avoid problems, you should turn off auto update for the Amazon store if you plan to use only Google Play from now on, or vice-versa if you want to continue to primarily use Amazon, and manually manage Google Play apps.
9. At this time, you should refer to step 10 above - restart your phone, and proceed to install Google Maps, then Pokemon GO as described.

Comment: It looks like the highest version of Fire OS for Fire Phone is 4.6.6.1 for an unlocked device, so this might not apply to your handset.

Comment: Please summarize the info contained at the link.  That way, if ever the page goes down, your answer is still valid.

Comment: Will do, as soon as I have the time.

Comment: Answer updated with procedure for Fire OS 5 per original link, and possible steps to achieve the same results under Fire OS 4.6 for Fire Phone.